# Howarthia Attenuata or fasciata?

Tags: identification, succulents

Which of these is this plant? Is caring for them similar or different?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the wikipedia entry for [Haworthiopsis attenuata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthiopsis_attenuata) - in the description section there is an attempt to draw a distinction between the two species based on where the tubercles occur on the leaves, along with rather minute details about the leaf shape.

Both species require good drainage, with more water in the heat of summer than in winter, and good bright indirect light. Too much light can change the leaf colour, causing washing out to neutral whites which are less attractive than the green.

Comment: Ha! I was confused cause the top side has barely any tubercles.